# How to redistribute connected /32 with quagga ospfd?

Tags: ospf, quagga

I have a VM host which acts as a quagga router. It announces routes to its hosted VM's (I don't use bridges, only routed VM's)

It works well when tun interface is configured with a /30 ; for example :

```
$ ip a
4: gentoo: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 500
    link/ether 2a:c8:0a:ae:cc:c1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.42.1.5/30 brd 10.42.1.7 scope global gentoo
    inet6 fe80::5c23:52ff:fec1:f2b7/128 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::28c8:aff:feae:ccc1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

But I want to put some publicy-routed IP's on some VMs, without wasting 3 IP's for the network, broadcast, and host IP ; for example :

```
$ ip ro
94.23.110.211 dev gentoo  scope link
```

The route is shown in "show ip route" quagga command

```
arrakeen# show ip route  
Codes: K - kernel route, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, O - OSPF,
       I - ISIS, B - BGP, > - selected route, * - FIB route
O   0.0.0.0/0 [110/110] via 10.42.42.1, eth0, 00:01:24
K>* 0.0.0.0/0 via 10.42.42.1, eth0
O>* 10.0.0.0/24 [110/20] via 10.42.42.1, eth0, 00:01:25
C>* 10.0.42.21/32 is directly connected, eth0
O>* 10.42.0.0/24 [110/20] via 10.42.42.1, eth0, 00:01:25
O   10.42.1.4/30 [110/10] is directly connected, gentoo, 00:01:35
C>* 10.42.1.4/30 is directly connected, gentoo
K>* 10.42.1.6/32 via 10.42.1.5, gentoo
O   10.42.42.0/24 [110/10] is directly connected, eth0, 00:01:35
C>* 10.42.42.0/24 is directly connected, eth0
O>* 10.242.0.1/32 [110/30] via 10.42.42.1, eth0, 00:01:25
O>* 10.255.0.1/32 [110/30] via 10.42.42.1, eth0, 00:01:25
O>* 10.255.0.2/32 [110/20] via 10.42.42.1, eth0, 00:01:25
O   94.23.110.210/32 [110/10] is directly connected, eth0, 00:01:35
C>* 94.23.110.210/32 is directly connected, eth0
K>* 94.23.110.211/32 is directly connected, gentoo
C>* 127.0.0.0/8 is directly connected, lo
```

But as you can see, it's not in OSPF's fib

```
arrakeen# show ip ospf route  
============ OSPF network routing table ============
N    10.0.0.0/24           [20] area: 0.0.0.0
                           via 10.42.42.1, eth0
N    10.42.0.0/24          [20] area: 0.0.0.0
                           via 10.42.42.1, eth0
N    10.42.1.4/30          [10] area: 0.0.0.0
                           directly attached to gentoo
N    10.42.1.36/30         [10] area: 0.0.0.0
N    10.42.42.0/24         [10] area: 0.0.0.0
                           directly attached to eth0
                           via 10.42.42.1, eth0
N    10.242.0.1/32         [30] area: 0.0.0.0
                           via 10.42.42.1, eth0
N    10.255.0.1/32         [30] area: 0.0.0.0
                           via 10.42.42.1, eth0
N    10.255.0.2/32         [20] area: 0.0.0.0
                           via 10.42.42.1, eth0
N    94.23.110.210/32      [10] area: 0.0.0.0
                           directly attached to eth0
N    94.23.110.218/32      [30] area: 0.0.0.0
                           via 10.42.42.1, eth0

============ OSPF router routing table =============
R    10.42.42.1            [10] area: 0.0.0.0, ASBR
                           via 10.42.42.1, eth0

============ OSPF external routing table ===========
N E1 0.0.0.0/0             [110] tag: 0
                           via 10.42.42.1, eth0
```

Is there a way to force them into ospf ?

Here is the ospfd.conf :

```
! -*- ospf -*-
!
hostname arrakeen
!
interface eth0
!
router ospf
 ospf router-id 10.42.42.21
 redistribute static
 redistribute connected
 network 10.42.1.0/24 area 0
 network 10.42.42.0/24 area 0
 network 94.23.110.210/28 area 0
!
log file /var/log/quagga/ospfd.log
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redistribute kernel` did the trick

Comment: You should add the router to Quagga and use `redistribute static` though.